# Austrian citizenship language skills

Tags: citizenship, austria

I have been residing in Austria for 6 years. I also have a long-term EU residence permit. I have mental sickness and I have a certificate from the public health doctor that I can't learn German. Is that paper eligible also for the language requirements for citizenship?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The question is perfectly clear and reasonable.

Comment: [This page](http://www.migration.gv.at/en/living-and-working-in-austria/integration-and-citizenship/citizenship/) says there are exceptions for mental conditions, especially speech and hearing impairments. I'd suggest you fill in the contact form there and ask about your specific case.